# jQuery form plugin - abort request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am trying to abort a [jQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form) plugin ajax request.

**NOTE:** I am talking about this plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form, not `$.ajax()`

I generally do this to abort `$.ajax()` request:

```
if(typeof this.query !== 'undefined'){
    this.query.abort();
}

this.query = jQuery.ajax({
...
...
});
```

but with [jQuery from plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form), this does not work. I seen some solutions on SO, which uses `beforeSend` to abort, but that solution will not work for me.

I want to check if ajax request running for same form, then abort previous request before sending new request.

Please suggest a way to abort [jQuery from](http://jquery.malsup.com/form) request.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the `xhr` from the malsup form and abort the request like so:

```
var form = $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({ ... });
var xhr = form.data('jqxhr');

xhr.abort();
```